# Small question about convergence for Euler product of zeta-function

Tags: analysis, number-theory, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, euler-product

Can anyone offer some clarification on the following equivalence? Perhaps as happens too often, I was told the statement follows from 'basic analysis', and while this is probably true, I can't seem to get it to work! Here is the claim:

For all $s\in \mathbb{C}$ with Re($s$)$>1$, the product 
$
\displaystyle\prod_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}
$
converges if and only if the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{p \text{ prime}} {p^{-s}}$ converges.

Comment: Is the summation over primes?

Comment: Yes, the sum is over all primes.

Comment: $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ converges in $\mathbb{C}^*$ iff $\log(\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}})=-\sum_p \log(1-p^{-s})$ converges in $\mathbb{C}/2\pi \mathbb{Z}$.
 

Taking the usual branch we have $-\log(1-z)= z+O(z^2)$ so that $-\log(1-p^{-s})= p^{-s}+O(p^{-2s}))$.

Finally, $\sum_p |p^{-2s}|$ converges for $Re(s) > 1/2$ and hence for $Re(s) > 1/2$ : $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ converges iff $\sum_p p^{-s}$ converges.

Comment: See Ahlfors, Ch. 5 section 2.2 for an elegant discussion that should clarify this question